# JSON array string conversion in Golang

Tags: go

I have a JSON array string like,

```
str = '[{"a":"1","b":"1"},{"a":"2","b":"2"}]'
```

In JS, I can parse it easily.

```
let data = JSON.parse(str)
// data is ARRAY[2] [{a:"1", b:"1"}, {a:"2", b:"2"}]
```

In Golang, how can I parse the string?

Eventually I'd like to validate whether the string is JSON format(object or array) or not.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-Unmarshal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go you would try to unmarshal your data into each of the two types you are interested in testing - array (slice), and object (map).   This code will run two tests, one of each type you wanted to test for.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    tests := [][]byte{
        []byte(`[{"a":"1","b":"1"},{"a":"2","b":"2"}]`),
        []byte(`{"a":"1","b":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}`),
    }

    for _, test := range tests {
        kind, err := getKind(test)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s is type %s\n", string(test), kind)

    }
}

func getKind(d []byte) (string, error) {
    var a []interface{}
    var m map[string]interface{}
    var e error

    e = json.Unmarshal(d, &a)
    if e != nil {
        e = json.Unmarshal(d, &m)
        if e != nil {
            return "", e
        }
        return "map", nil
    }
    return "array", nil
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[{"a":"1","b":"1"},{"a":"2","b":"2"}] is type array
{"a":"1","b":[{"a":1,"b":2}]} is type map
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    tests := [][]byte{
        []byte(`[{"a":"1","b":"1"},{"a":"2","b":"2"}]`),
        []byte(`{"a":"1","b":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}`),
    }
    for _, b := range tests {
        var v interface{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(b, &v)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        // use reflect or switch-case
        fmt.Println(string(b), "type is:", reflect.TypeOf(v))

        switch val := v.(type) {
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(val, "is array")
        case map[string]interface{}:
            fmt.Println(val, "is map")
        }
    }
}

// output:
// [{"a":"1","b":"1"},{"a":"2","b":"2"}] type is: []interface {}
// [map[a:1 b:1] map[a:2 b:2]] is array
// {"a":"1","b":[{"a":1,"b":2}]} type is: map[string]interface {}
// map[a:1 b:[map[a:1 b:2]]] is map
```